# vb.net combobox displaymember saves to database not valuemember

Tags: vb.net

I've searched regarding displaymember and valuemember of combobox, but I think none of them fits my need.

Here's my scenario

I have two table, emp201 and department_misc

emp201 contains empno, name, department, etc.
department_misc contains code, description.

Here's my code to fill combobox:

```
    Public Sub Auto1(ByVal cmb As ComboBox, ByVal strTbl As String)
            Dim locDa As New DataSet
            rs = cn.Execute("SELECT Code, Description FROM " & strTbl)
            locDaOle.Fill(locDa, rs, strTbl)
            cmb.DisplayMember = "department"
            cmb.ValueMember = "Code"
            cmb.DataSource = locDa.Tables(strTbl)
    End Sub
```

After that, this is my code to bind using bindingsource

```
Public Sub bindControls(ByVal fFormName As Form, ByVal strFormName As String, ByVal strTable As String)

    Dim ctrl As Control
    Try
        ds = New DataSet()
        sda = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + strTable, oleDBConn)
        sda.Fill(ds)
        bsSource = New BindingSource()
        bsSource.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        sda.Fill(ds, strTable)

        For Each ctrl In fFormName.Controls
            If ctrl.AccessibleName = "" Then Continue For
            If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox)) Or _
                (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(ComboBox)) Then
                ctrl.DataBindings.Clear()
                ctrl.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bsSource, ctrl.AccessibleName)) 


            ElseIf (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(CheckBox)) Then
                ctrl.DataBindings.Clear()
                ctrl.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Checked", bsSource, ctrl.AccessibleName))
                MAINFORM.BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bsSource

            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I used accessiblename to store the field in database, since datafield in .net is not available.

Then after I bound the combobox using bindingsource, it works, but when I browse the data saved to database, it saved the displaymember. Is there a way i can save the code not the description? or maybe I am wrong using the displaymember and valuemember?

Comment: Hi there. If you are composing your questions on a mobile phone, and this prevents you from using the Shift key, please use a laptop or a PC. Writing in all-lower-case reduces readability, and it creates extra work for volunteer editors, who already struggle to keep up with level of improvements required. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the code you have shown will cause anything to be saved to the database. I'm assuming that you have your `emp201` table bound to other controls, including that `ComboBox`.  If you're expecting the `Code` of the selected department to be saved into a another record then you need to bind your `ComboBox` to that record.  That would look something like this:

```
cmb.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", myBindingSource, "department")
```

When you select an item in a `ComboBox`, the `SelectedValue` property will return the value from the column/property whose name is assigned to the `ValueMember`.

Comment: sorry, i edit my question, i didnt include my code for binding

Comment: The issue is obvious then. You are binding the `Text` property of every control and, as I've already told you, it's the `SelectedValue` of the `ComboBox` you should be binding. As you're seeing, the `Text` property returns a value from the column/property specified by the `DisplayMember`. If you want a value from the column/property specified by the `ValueMember` then you need to use the `SelectedValue`. You should already know that because you should have read the documentation for the `ComboBox` and its properties.

Comment: oh finally i get it! Thanks for your answer! i replaced text to SelectedValue. it works! sorry i just moved from vb6 to vb.net. anyway Thank you so much and God bless!

Comment: Please make sure to accept the answer if it resolves your issue. That way, everyone can see that you no longer need help without having to open the thread.